# Display Large Image on mouse hover with auto position in magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, tooltip, qtip

I am newbie in magento.

I want give a effect on mouse hover large image display with auto position for product listing page in magento.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
I used qtip for displayed large images in mouse hover.

Here is the link for that.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/